# How to get the coordinates of an item that the player is holding in Minecraft? Using MinecraftForge

Tags: coordinates, minecraft, minecraft-forge, spawning

I am using Minecraft Forge and I want to know how to get the coordinates of a Block or an Item that the player is holding or looking at. Or It can also be just a block that the player just broke. In any case, I need to get those coordinates to be able to change them in a way that makes y=Sin(x) and I would keep looping and spawning copies of the same item so that it plots the Sinus function.
I would really appreaciate your help.. I am stuck with this for days.
Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the block a player is looking at:

```
MovingObjectPosition mop = Minecraft.getMinecraft().renderViewEntity.rayTrace(200, 1.0F);
if(mop != null)
{
int blockHitSide = mop.sideHit;
Block blockLookingAt = worldObj.getBlock(mop.blockX, mop.blockY, mop.blockZ) ;
}
```

The block variable would be `blockLookingAt`

Also, you may want to check out http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/

Comment: I tried to use renderViewEntity but it didn't want to work, I don't know why they don't let me use it. Therefore I used objectMOuseOver instead: 
MovingObjectPosition mop= Minecraft.getMinecraft().objectMouseOver;
int x=mop.getBlockPos().getX();
int y=mop.getBlockPos().getY();
int c=y - 20*x;
int i;
for(i=x;i<(i+100);){
 y=20*i + c;
 i+=2;
 x=i;
_______________
Is there something wrong with this? What should I write now to set the mop position to the new x and y every time inside the loop?
I am trying to make it move in a "y=20x +c" motion
Thank you so much for your answer by the way.